# how to configure and deploy QT to run platform independently?

Tags: qt

I am new to QT.  I am using "qt creator 5"  with "opencv" on ubuntu 13.04. I want to run program written and executed on my machine is to be executed as well on other windows and Ubuntu machine.

thanks in advance

Comment: you'll need to [cross compile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compile), because ubuntu and windows expect different formats for their executables

Comment: Check the documentation about [Deploying Qt Applications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment.html). For cross compiling windows applications on linux, see [MXE](http://mxe.cc/).

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux:**

You should place Qt so files along the release version of your executable. These are `libQtCore.so`, `libQtGui.so` and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These so files are in your installed Qt Directory in lib folder or in director `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`. If you are using plugins you should place their so files in a folder named `plugins` beside your binary. In case of using icons and images you should ship their so files like `libqico.so` and `libqsvg.so` in a folder named `imageformats`.

**On Windows:**

You can compile your code on Windows using Qt Creator and Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler.

You should place Qt DLLs along the release version of your executable. These are `Qt5Core.dll`, `Qt5Gui.dll` and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These dll files are in your installed Qt Directory in bin folder. You should also place `msvcr100.dll` and `msvcp100.dll` in case you are using MSVS2010. If you are using plugins you should place their dll in a folder named `plugins` beside your exe. In case of using icons and images you should ship their dlls like `qico.dll` and `qsvg.dll` in a folder named `imageformats`.