# How to create portable gui programs

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

i have a lot of interest in programming, particularly creating gui programs. i have done some searches on the web and know that i need some libraries(qt for example) in order to create the gui interface, which i have no problem with. my question is that once i have created the program(lets say in c++ and qt) and compiled it, will it be able to run in a computer that does not have the qt library installed? and in case it wont, how can i create a gui program that does not need any special libraries to render the interface?

Comment: You can link *statically*, which pulls in all the code from the library into the executable. Then it will most likely be able to run on other computers with same platform and operating system. However, you can't take an executable program from e.g. Linux and run it on Windows, or a program compiled for ARM and run it on x86.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/deployment.html

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285259/how-to-configure-and-deploy-qt-to-run-platform-independently/21351069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Qt you need either to deploy static apps (for which you need to rebuild your Qt for static builds, and that is not a trivial task usually) or to supply all needed Qt/compiler libraries together with your application.

Anyway you can start [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Deploying_Qt_Applications) or [here](http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=138) (the latter is a quick guide for deploying dynamic apps on different platforms).

Also, if you don't need cross-compiling to different platforms - you'd be good with using native platform-dependant API (such as WinAPI for Windows f.e.) that usually compiles under most compilers on that platform cause all the libraries needed are already supplied with the platform.

Answer (score 2):

Qt is really good, but remember that it's not allowed to deploy applications using the libraries as static, it's paid. ("Static linking is not subject to the new LGPL-licensing, thus you'll have to buy a commercial license if don't want to release your own code under the GPL." - [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Deploying_Qt_Applications#Cons)) Qt allows only, for free (under license), shared/dynamic linking.

wxWidgets allows static linking for free. Maybe GTKmm as well.